# "Inverting" a Markov chain transition matrix into a weighted, undirected graph

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk, transition-matrix

Suppose I have some normalized transition matrix $P$ for a Markov chain, and suppose I know a priori that there exists a weighted, undirected graph $G$ for which a random walk on $G$ would have the same transition probabilities as $P$. How would I go about deriving $G$ from $P$ (up to a constant factor on edge weights)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an explanation of what's going on here in Chapter 9 of *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Wilmer, Peres, which is available online.

Briefly, we can say the following: such a weighted graph exists if and only if the Markov chain is [reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Time_reversal). If the Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$, then reversibility is equivalent to the [detailed balance equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#Reversible_Markov_chains)
$$
\pi(x)P(x,y) = \pi(y) P(y,x)
$$
holding for all states $x,y$.

With that said, one valid weighting is to take $\pi(x) \cdot P(x,y)$ to be the weight for the edge $xy$.